# Typescript/ts-loader error for typescript dependency

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, ts-loader

I have a typescript npm module (project B) which uses `typescript@3.7.5` and `ts-loader@6.2.1` which works fine. I can successfully run my tests inside that project.

I have another typescript project (project A) which pulls in project B as a dependency.

Project A uses `webpack@3.12.0` so I am locked into using `typescript@2.9.2` and `ts-loader@3.5.0`. I am getting an error when trying to build with the Project B dependency. 
Logs show that the error is in the `ts-loader` located inside Project B

Also an extra note the Project B is linked globally `npm link project-b`.

```
ERROR in ../project-b/node_modules/ts-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!../project-b/src/../Component.vue
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProgram' of null
    at Object.getEmitOutput (/Users/username/../project-b/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/instances.js:369:41)
    at getEmit (/Users/username/../project-b/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:275:37)
    at successLoader (/Users/username/../project-b/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:67:15)
    at Object.loader (/Users/username/../project-b/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:22:12)
```

Is there any way to tell ts-loader/webpack to use ts-loader/typescript versions or tsconfig.json from the root project (Project A) for the Project B dependency? Or is could it be solved via another configuration?

Comment: One of reasons to keep projects separate is that they can have different infrastructure without dependency conflicts. It probably would be better to build B and import as a lib (.js+.d.ts).

Comment: @EstusFlask This was my previous approach. Since this is a shared project not all modules are required by every consumer and the built files can get big and bloated. My desire is to keep the the end project as slim as possible and only import what I need.

Comment: You can build a lib to `es5` target with `es2015` modules, in terms of TS. This way unused imports will be tree-shaken by Webpack. This approach is very common in third-party libs (rxjs, ramda, etc), primarily because this prevents bloating. FWIW, I've never seen anyone doing what you originally asked, dependency hell isn't the greatest thing to deal with.